# Progress Bar цвет пустой части

Tags: java, android, progress-bar

Как можно настроить Progress Bar, чтобы было примерно как на скрине
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Например 50% заполнено зеленым,а остальное вторым цветом.
По факту нужно,чтобы зеленый накладывался на второй цвет...например если 10% зеленого,то 90% оранжевый и т.д

Comment: Android? Swing? JavaFX? Что-то еще?

Comment: @Эникейщик Я вроде тег поставил,что java)Да,в андроид студио.

Comment: Далеко не все, что пишется на яве, имеет отношение к андроиду :) Думаю, что даже не бОльшая часть.

Comment: @Эникейщик догадываюсь))Я просто думал,по скрину ясно будет)Моя ошибка,признаю)

Answer (score 1):

Создал drawable/test.xml с таким содержимым

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<!-- Define the background properties like color etc -->
<item android:id="@android:id/background">
    <shape>
        <gradient
            android:startColor="@color/DarkOrange"
            android:centerColor="@color/DarkOrange"
            android:centerY="1.0"
            android:endColor="@color/DarkOrange"
            android:angle="270"
            />
    </shape>
</item>

<!-- Define the progress properties like start color, end color etc -->
<item android:id="@android:id/progress">
    <clip>
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:startColor="@color/colorAccent"
                android:centerColor="@color/colorAccent"
                android:centerY="1.0"
                android:endColor="@color/colorAccent"
                android:angle="270"
                />
        </shape>
    </clip>
</item>
```

И вот так подключил

```
 <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progressBar3"
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="5dp"
                android:progress="30"
                android:progressDrawable="@drawable/test" />
```

Получилось в итоге

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Насчет "накладывался" не знаю, но у прогрессбара есть параметр `android:progressBackgroundTint`, который задает фоновый цвет (т.е. цвет "пустой части" и параметр [android:progressTintMode](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html#attr_android:progressTintMode), который определяет режим совмещения основного и фонового цветов. Можете поиграться с add или multiply. А можно изначально прямо задать два нужных цвета.

```
android:progressTint="#00ff00"
android:progressBackgroundTint="#990000"
android:progressTintMode="add"
```

Выбираете два нужных цвета, в коде потом устанавливаете на нужную позицию

```
ProgressBar pb = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
pb.setProgress(int value);
```

А для увеличения высоты полоски можно использовать параметр

```
android:scaleY="8"
```

Comment: Чуть ниже накидал свой вариант)Работает как хотел)

Comment: зачем изобретать велосипед, когда уже есть встроенные средства :)

Comment: XD велосипед всегда интереснее)А в друг прорыв будет технологический)